# Apply a class if element undefined - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to apply a class to an element only if an element in an object undefined/null.
I am trying the way below, but not succeeding...

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts.records | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" ng-class="post.record.time !='' ? 'not-available' : '' ">
    <a href="record.php?id={{post.record.ID}}">
       <b>{{post.record.name}}</b>
    </a>
</li>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts.records | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" ng-class="{'not-available': post.record.time !=''}">
    <a href="record.php?id={{post.record.ID}}">
       <b>{{post.record.name}}</b>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: The class applied to all list items, either available or not.

Comment: This is better way of doing it (without function). Thanks @wayne

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts.records | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" ng-class="getClass(post)">
    <a href="record.php?id={{post.record.ID}}">
       <b>{{post.record.name}}</b>
    </a>
</li>
```

JS

```
$scope.getClass=function(post){
  if(_isUndefinedOrNull(post.record.time))
     return 'not-available';
  else
     '';
}

function _isUndefinedOrNull(val) {
   return angular.isUndefined(val) || val === null || val === '';
}//
```

Comment: This is giving the same response as wayne's answer...
applied to all list items.

Comment: Done it, needed to change != to equal with additional condition of undefined. 
Thanks